# echo div class 'last' in for each loop

Tags: php, class, echo

Good morning all. 
Just having a little issue with a foreach loop, where I am echoing a div class="related-product', and would like to target the last div, to a 'class="related-product last".

```
<?php 
$relatedProd = explode(';', $row['relatedProd']);

if (sizeof($relatedProd) > 0) {
    echo '<h4>Hello World!</h4>';
}
foreach ($relatedProd as $key => $value) {
    echo '<div class="one_third product-table <?php
    if ( $key == ( count( $relatedProd ) -1 ) ) echo
    last ">';

    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `<?php` in your echo and also an if statement?

Comment: I think you are asking about your attempt,its better to ask about the problem.See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Assuming that the 'last' class adds to the style of the div you could use css to achieve this without needing to add the 'last' part.
viz: .relate-product:last-of-type{ /*rules*/ }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, first its a bit easier to read and therefore maintain and debug, also you dont need to start another `<?php` while you are in a PHP block.

```
<?php 
   $relatedProd = explode(';', $row['relatedProd']);

   if (sizeof($relatedProd) > 0) {
      echo '<h4>Hello World!</h4>';
   }
   foreach ($relatedProd as $key => $value) {
      $extra = $key == count( $relatedProd ) -1 ? 'last' : '';
      echo '<div class="one_third product-table ' . $extra . '"></div>'; 
   }
?>
```

Comment: That's the badger ! Thank you kindly for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job by assigning the value directly within the php loop without the `<?php` tags:

```
$lastStr = "";
foreach ($relatedProd as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == count($relatedProd)-1) {
        $lastStr = " last";
    }
    echo "<div class=\"one_third product-table{$lastStr}\"></div>";
}
```